# error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

I am trying to make use scala test with gradle.
        Following is a snapshot of how my build.gradle looks like.
        My IntelliJ SDKs for Scala too points to the most recent ones. I have been working on this for past 2 days yet no success.I have tried changing the libraries,or the SourceSets but nothing seems to change the error messages.
    If I do not make use of SourceSets,it throws errors on all the class files,irrespective of Java or Scala.
    Following is how my folder structure looks like:

```
 src
    -main
        -java
        -scala
    -test
       -groovy
       -scala 

    //start of my gradle file.
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'wrapper'
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    version = '1'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        //json marshalling
        compile 'org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:3.2.11'

        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'

        //scala
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"

        //scala
        testCompile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
        testCompile(group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.11', version: '2.2.4')
    }

    sourceSets {
    main {
          scala {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/scala','src/main/java']
                }
            }
            test {
                scala {
                    srcDirs = ['src/test/scala']
                }
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/main"
            }
        }
        //not sure whether an Ant task helps? I grabbed from after a google search.
        test << {
            ant.taskdef(
                    name: 'scalatest',
                    classname: 'org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestAntTask',
                    classpath: classpath.asPath
            )
            println("test classes dir" + testClassesDir)
            ant.scalatest(
                    runpath: testClassesDir,
                    haltonfailure: 'true',
                    fork: 'false') {
                reporter(type: 'stderr')
                reporter(type: 'junitxml', directory: 'build/reports/junitxml')
            }
        }


    Following is the command I use to run the tests:
    ./gradlew clean test

    and the error log reports:

    :compileTestScala
    error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'.
    Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
    because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
    missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
    A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.
    one error found

    Any pointers would be helpful.
```

Comment: I also tried deleting the local .ivy2 cache,it still does not help.

Comment: so ,i added this to my build.gradle: task spec(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/test', '-o']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}
and i get this:
[ant:scalac] error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'.